# Test if element is in array in bash

Tags: bash, array

Is there a nice way of checking if an array has an element in bash (better than looping through)?

Alternatively, is there another way to check if a number or string equals any of a set of predefined constants?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In Bash 4, you can use associative arrays:

```
# set up array of constants
declare -A array
for constant in foo bar baz
do
    array[$constant]=1
done

# test for existence
test1="bar"
test2="xyzzy"

if [[ ${array[$test1]} ]]; then echo "Exists"; fi    # Exists
if [[ ${array[$test2]} ]]; then echo "Exists"; fi    # doesn't
```

To set up the array initially you could also do direct assignments:

```
array[foo]=1
array[bar]=1
# etc.
```

or this way:

```
array=([foo]=1 [bar]=1 [baz]=1)
```

Comment: Actually, the [[]] test doesn't work in the case the value is empty. E.g., "array['test']=''". In this case, the key 'test' exists, and you can see it listed with ${!array[@]}, but "[[ ${array['test']} ]]; echo $?" echoes 1, not 0.

Comment: `${array[$test1]}` is simple but has a problem: it won't work if you use `set -u` in your scripts (which is recommended), as you'd get "unbound variable".

Comment: @tokland: Who recommends it? I certainly don't.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: Ok, *some people* recommend it, but I think it would be nice to have a solution that works regardless the value of these flags.

Comment: Some posts about `set -u`: http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/writing-robust-shell-scripts.html, http://blog.hashbang0.com/2010/05/18/robust-bash-scripts-part-one/, http://www.openews.net/2012/bash-script-to-write-robust/.

Answer (score 10):

It's an old question, but I think what is the simplest solution has not appeared yet: `test ${array[key]+_}`. Example:

```
declare -A xs=([a]=1 [b]="")
test ${xs[a]+_} && echo "a is set"
test ${xs[b]+_} && echo "b is set"
test ${xs[c]+_} && echo "c is set"
```

Outputs:

```
a is set
b is set
```

To see how this work check [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22491).

Comment: The info manual recommneds you to use `env` to avoid ambiguities in aliases, progs and other functions that may have adopted the name "test". As above `env test ${xs[a]+_} && echo "a is set"`. You can also get this functionality using double-brackets, the same trick then checking for null: `[[ ! -z "${xs[b]+_}" ]] && echo "b is set"`

Comment: Also you can use the even simpler `[[ ${xs[b]+set} ]]`

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to test if an element of an associative array exists (not set), this is different from empty:

```
isNotSet() {
    if [[ ! ${!1} && ${!1-_} ]]
    then
        return 1
    fi
}
```

Then use it:

```
declare -A assoc
KEY="key"
isNotSet assoc[${KEY}]
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
  echo "${KEY} is not set."
fi
```

Comment: just a note: declare -A doesn't work on bash 3.2.39 (debian lenny), but it works on bash 4.1.5 (debian squeeze)

Comment: Associative arrays were introduced in Bash 4.

Comment: note that `if ! some_check then return 1` = `some_check`. So: `isNotSet() { [[ ... ]] }`. Check my solution below, you can do it in a simple check.

Answer (score 4):

You can see if an entry is present by piping the contents of the array to grep.

```
 printf "%s\n" "${mydata[@]}" | grep "^${val}$"
```

You can also get the index of an entry with  grep -n, which returns the line number of a match (remember to subtract 1 to get zero-based index)
This will be reasonably quick except for very large arrays.

```
# given the following data
mydata=(a b c "hello world")

for val in a c hello "hello world"
do
           # get line # of 1st matching entry
    ix=$( printf "%s\n" "${mydata[@]}" | grep -n -m 1 "^${val}$" | cut -d ":" -f1 )

    if [[ -z $ix ]]
    then
        echo $val missing
    else
         # subtract 1.  Bash arrays are zero-based, but grep -n returns 1 for 1st line, not 0 
        echo $val found at $(( ix-1 ))
    fi
done

a found at 0
c found at 2
hello missing
hello world found at 3
```

explanation:

- `$( ... )` is the same as using backticks to capture output of a command into a variable
- `printf`  outputs mydata one element per line
- (all quotes necessary, along with `@` instead of `*.`  this avoids splitting "hello world" into 2 lines)
- `grep` searches for exact string:  `^` and `$` match beginning and end of line
- `grep -n` returns line #, in form of 4:hello world
- `grep -m 1` finds first match only
- `cut` extracts just the line number
- subtract 1 from returned line number.

You can of course fold the subtraction into the command.  But then test for -1 for missing:

```
ix=$(( $( printf "%s\n" "${mydata[@]}" | grep -n -m 1 "^${val}$" | cut -d ":" -f1 ) - 1 ))

if [[ $ix == -1 ]]; then echo missing; else ... fi
```

- `$(( ... ))` does integer arithmetic

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
function in_array {
  ARRAY=$2
  for e in ${ARRAY[*]}
  do
    if [[ "$e" == "$1" ]]
    then
      return 0
    fi
  done
  return 1
}

my_array=(Drupal Wordpress Joomla)
if in_array "Drupal" "${my_array[*]}"
  then
    echo "Found"
  else
    echo "Not found"
fi
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you are suggesting this approach? OP asked if there is a way to do it *without looping through the array*, which is what you are doing in `in_array`. Cheers

Comment: Well, at least that loop is capsuled in a function, which might be good enough for many cases (with small data sets), and doesn't require bash 4+. Probably `${ARRAY[@]}` should be used.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it properly without looping unless you have **very** limited data in the array.

Here is one simple variant, this would correctly say that `"Super User"` exists in the array. But it would also say that `"uper Use"` is in the array.

```
MyArray=('Super User' 'Stack Overflow' 'Server Fault' 'Jeff' );
FINDME="Super User"

FOUND=`echo ${MyArray[*]} | grep "$FINDME"`

if [ "${FOUND}" != "" ]; then
  echo Array contains: $FINDME
else
  echo $FINDME not found
fi

#
# If you where to add anchors < and > to the data it could work
# This would find "Super User" but not "uper Use"
#

MyArray2=('<Super User>' '<Stack Overflow>' '<Server Fault>' '<Jeff>' );

FOUND=`echo ${MyArray2[*]} | grep "<$FINDME>"`

if [ "${FOUND}" != "" ]; then
  echo Array contains: $FINDME
else
  echo $FINDME not found
fi
```

The problem is that there is no easy way to add the anchors (that I can think of) besides looping through the array. Unless you can add them before you put them in the array...

Comment: It is a nice solution when the constants are alphanumeric, though (with `grep "\b$FINDME\b"`). Probably could work with non-alphanumeric constants that have no spaces, with `"(^| )$FINDME(\$| )"` (or something like that... I have never been able to learn what flavor of regexp grep uses.)